# Materialize css not working with static css files

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, materialize

I am trying to implement a navbar on my web page. I've done it so far but when I tried opening the page on mobile it didn't show any navbar link. I came across this 'hamburger menu' and the code below works perfectly , the only problem is when I try to replace

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">
```

with

```html
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'competition/materialize.css' %}"/>
```

which refers to the css file on my folder, it stops working. By stops working I mean that the collapsible menu doesn't work on mobile and on pc the collapsible menu shows up overlaying the logo text. I need to use the css file on a local machine to be able to edit the colors of navbar.

```html
{% load static %}
<head>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'competition/materialize.css' %}"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      <!-- this part is important! -->
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".button-collapse").sideNav();
      });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
    <div class="nav-wrapper">
      <a href="#" class="brand-logo">Logo</a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">JavaScript</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li><a href="sass.html">Sass</a></li>
        <li><a href="badges.html">Components</a></li>
        <li><a href="collapsible.html">Javascript</a></li>
        <li><a href="mobile.html">Mobile</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: why would you need it local to change the navbar css?, you can just use the `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.100.2/css/materialize.min.css">` and  then overrule it by your local css, and try to use `!important` behind the `background-color:` if it doesn't overrule it

Comment: Why does it stop working with a local copy though?